# iPad: Cursor cannot be seen or moved when creating a cover letter on Careers 2.0

Tags: bug, status-deferred, jobs

Using an iPad to apply for a job on Careers 2.0, when creating a cover letter, the cursor is invisible and the cursor position cannot be moved, so correcting errors is not possible!

Comment: It might be an aptitude test.  An iPad doesn't support copy/paste?

Comment: Is there *normally* a cursor when you use this feature on other platforms? Can you post a screenshot of what it looks like on the iPad? What happens when you try to select text as you would elsewhere on the iPad?

Comment: No idea how to screenshot on an iPad, but it seems the cursor is lost when moving from the covering letter field to another field and then back again. When trying to reposition/select text no cursor appears in the magnifying glass and it would seem that the cursor is not just invisible as the insert position always returns to after the last character in the entered text. When trying to copy/paste the menu appears in odd places and copy never actually copies any text - as none can ever be selected.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow has [discontinued](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293) Stack Overflow Jobs and Developer Story on March 31, 2022.

Answer (score 1):

This has been added to our trello board.